# typeof is reporting string instead of number

Tags: javascript, typeof

Somehow a variable with the data 4 inside of it is reporting as a string with the typeof operator instead of as number? Is this any issue with the Code Academy editor?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/09dBW.png

```
var languages = {
    english: "Hello!",
    french: "Bonjour!",
    notALanguage: 4,
    spanish: "Hola!"
};

// print hello in the 3 different languages
for(var item in languages) {
    if(typeof item !== "number") {
        console.log(languages[item] + " " + typeof item);
    }
}
```

Comment: While *item* is a variable, its value is a property name (e.g. 'english', 'french', 'notALanguage', etc.), and Object property names are defined to be Strings in the language specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item` is the keys in the object `languages` not the values of those properties. To check the type of the values you need to test `languages[item]`

```
// print hello in the 3 different languages
for(var item in languages) {
    if(typeof languages[item] !== "number") {
        console.log(languages[item] + " " + typeof item, item);
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/egoc843t/)

- [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: Hmm, guess I'm confused because the instructions say "Remember you can figure out the type of a variable by using typeof myVariable;" and I assumed that `item` would represent say `languages.english`; I figured it out with your example, thank you!

Comment: Why would you assume that `item` would represent anything other than `item`?

Comment: @torazaburo sorry... is that to me? if so can you clarify.. I'm not clear

Comment: @torazaburo I meant I thought it would represent the value of of `languages.english` I'm coming from C# so I didn't understand that it would represent the property name rather than the value itself.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I meant the OP, sorry.